# Having a Master to control two separate system with ROS-Hydro

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am newbie in ROS. I wonder if we can create a master control to interact with two separate systems which has ROS hydro installed. Or to be appropriate,  Can I control two separate ROS Hydro using another computer which acts like a master?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273565/having-a-master-to-control-two-separate-system-with-ros-hydro/) by [Brindha](https://answers.ros.org/users/32326/brindha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-10-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-20**:
Can you clarify why specifically for Hydro?

**Comment by [Brindha](https://answers.ros.org/users/32326/brindha/) on 2017-10-20**:
That is my requirement. I would like to know If this is possible.?

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-10-20**:
@Brindha do you mean [this](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines)?

**Comment by [Brindha](https://answers.ros.org/users/32326/brindha/) on 2017-10-20**:
Maybe this is the topic I am looking for. Thank you @l4ncelot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS provides this functionality. Have a look at [this](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines) guide on ROS across multiple machines. [Here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup) is network setup guide to make it work.

To launch nodes on different machines with single launch file have a look at roslaunch's machine tag [here](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/machine).

---

Originally posted by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) with karma: 826 on 2017-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1